# How do I search from the bottom up using a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

Here is an example of the type of text file I am trying to search (named usefile):

DOCK onomatopoeia
DOCK blah blah
blah DOCK blah
DOCK
blah blah blah
onomatopoeia
blah blah blah
blah blah DOCK
DOCK blah blah
DOCK blah
onomatopoeia

I am using a finditer statement to find everything between DOCK and onomatopoeia as follows:

```
re.finditer(r'((dock)(.+?)(onomatopoeia))', usefile, re.I|re.DOTALL)
```

Obviously Dock is a much more common word than onomatopoeia and I only want to grab text between the first instance of Dock before onomatopoeia.  The regex I am using above grabs text between the first instance of Dock and stops when it hits onomatopoeia, so I might get Dock Dock Dock Dock onomatopoeia when I really only wanted Dock onomatopoeia.

To be clear what I want from above is:
1.  DOCK onomatopoeia
2.  DOCK blah blah blah onomatopoeia
3.  DOCK blah onomatopoeia

Is there a way to search for onomatopoeia and go UP to the first instance of Dock, or a better way to solve my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it have a to be a regex based solution or can it use string functions?

Comment: It wouldn't have to be I suppose, but that is what I have been working with thus far.  Daniel's solution below seems to work great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A negative lookahead assertion will do the trick.

```
DOCK((?!DOCK).)+?onomatopoeia
```

Comment: Depending on specific use-case, may want to wrap DOCK in a pair of `\b` to ensure that, for example, "haddock" doesn't cause incorrect behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithmic approach:

- set pushing==false.
- Break your text apart into words (e.g. spans of letters) and loop over those.
- upon hitting a DOCK and pushing==false, push it onto a stack and set pushing = true
- if you hit ono... and pushing==true, print out whatever's on the stack plus ono..., then clear the stack and set pushing = false.
- any other word, if pushing==true, push it.
- DOCK, if pushing==true, clear the stack, then push your new DOCK.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems quite complicated.